Android WebView cannot render ChartJs bitmap on device but works in emulator
WebView does not create a bitmap when ChartJs is used in the webview.  The resulting bitmap is all white.  It does work on the emulator but not on an actual device.
UPDATE: I set hardwareAccelerated to false in AndroidManifest.xml and the problem is fixed.
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

Code:
fun screenshot (webView:WebView):Bitmap?{
    try {
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.width, webView.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        webView.draw(canvas)
        return bitmap
    }
    catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
}

I have the android:hardwareAccelerated="true" line in the Android Manifest, and WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw() in the App init, as well as binding.wvContent.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true before loading its Url.
Also tried:
fun screenShot(mWebView:WebView) {
    // measure the webview
    mWebView?.measure(
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0,View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
    )

    //layout of webview
    mWebView?.layout(0, 0, mWebView!!.measuredWidth, mWebView!!.getMeasuredHeight())

    mWebView?.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
    mWebView?.buildDrawingCache(true)//create Bitmap if measured height and width >0
    val bm = if (mWebView?.measuredWidth!! > 0 && mWebView?.measuredHeight!! > 0) {
        Bitmap.createBitmap(
            mWebView?.measuredWidth!!,
            mWebView?.measuredHeight!!,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        )
    }
    else null

    // Draw bitmap on canvas
    bm?.let {
        Canvas(bm).apply {
            drawBitmap(it, 0f, bm.height.toFloat(), Paint())
            mWebView?.draw(this)
        }
    }
}

Anyone have a solution to this?
Thanks

Have you disabled animation in the chart.js options (see comments in this post)?

I just tried that, animation: false, but still getting white bitmap when running on my phone, Samsung Galaxy A52 5G.  Works great on the emulator.  Going to dig a little more into bitmaps and hardware acceleration on a real device.

I corrected the problem by setting hardwareAccelated to false in AndroidManifest.xml:
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
I can now generate a bitmap of the chart and save it to a file.
